# MySQL: Update values with sum of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table setup like this

**Liabilities**:

```
Id | CustomerId | liabilities
---------------------------
9    90           1000
...
```

**Payments**:

```
Id | CustomerId | Payment
---------------------------
3    90           2500
4    91           1000
...
```

**Customer**:

```
Id | balance
---------------------------
90   1500
91   1000
...
```

As you can see, the balance for a customer is the sum of all its payments minus the sum of all its liabilities. What is an SQL query to update the balance?

Comment: You could consider scheduled events, more info here: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: This is a good point. But at this point I am actually just interested in getting a query that would do the update ... then the events are a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an `UPDATE` statement with `LEFT JOIN` operations to derived tables containing `Payments` and `Liabilities` aggregates:

```
UPDATE Customer AS c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerId, SUM(Payment) AS TotalPayment
  FROM Payments
  GROUP BY CustomerId
) AS p ON c.Id = p.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT CustomerId, SUM(liabilities) AS TotalLiabilities
  FROM Liabilities
  GROUP BY CustomerId
) AS l ON c.Id = l.CustomerId  
SET balance = COALESCE(TotalPayment, 0) - COALESCE(TotalLiabilities, 0)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af549/1)

Alternatively, you can use correlated subqueries in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Customer AS c 
SET balance = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Payment) 
                        FROM Payments 
                        WHERE CustomerId = c.Id) , 0)
              - 
              COALESCE((SELECT SUM(liabilities) 
                        FROM Liabilities 
                        WHERE CustomerId = c.Id)  , 0)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33741/1)